# Define virtual system variables for children applications

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a program that would run other application under given virtual environment. I am running another application like so:

```
Process app = new Process();
app.StartInfo.FileName = @"W:\path\to\app\some.exe";
app.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
app.Start();
```

Now I have faced an issue to change some system variables for application to be run. I have googled for this and could not found the solution. Anybody has any idea how to solve this problem, please help me?
Thanks.

**Update**

For example I want to set another `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME`, `AppData` variable for child application. Application could be: `Google Chrome`, `Notepad++` or simple `.bat` script for command line.

Comment: Which system variables would you like to change?

Comment: does your exe works fine when you run it directly without changing the system variable?

Comment: @S.Spieker for example `PATH` or `JAVA_HOME` or even `AppData`

Comment: @amitdayama yes, this is a simple application or even a bat file.

Comment: Then in that case you dont need to change the your system variable.. if you change your working directory while accessing the exe file then i guess it will work

Answer (score 0):

assuming you need to change path variable

```
string pathvariable=Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path",pathvariable+";"+"*you new value of path variable*");
```

if your exe file works fine when you access it directly then you dont need to change the your system variable.. if you change your working directory while accessing the exe file then i guess it will work

Comment: Dont you think this would change the systems PATH variable, not the virtual variable for the child application?